# CSS - Position fixed IE8 without changing doctype

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-position

This is a (was) very hot topic but I did not find a good answer for that.

So I am developing a plugin for a webshop and I need to integrate a popup window that has a `position:fixed`

The problem is that in IE8 position fixed has a doctype problem and **I cannot** change the default doctype of the website.

Can anyone tell me how to / or if it is possible to use `position:fixed` in IE8 without having to change doctype?

Edit: I am using default html5 doctype

Comment: can you provide a demo to show the problem?

Comment: What doctype *do* you have?

Comment: The default html5 <!DOCTYPE>

Comment: Then there is no problem with the doctype.

Comment: Are you maybe using an `X-UA-Compatible` header?

Comment: No X-UA-Compatible headers. That should do the trick? <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /> ?

Comment: 1) The default html5 doctype is `<!doctype html>`, not just `<!doctype>`
2) `position: fixed` works in IE8 regardless of doctype - you must be doing something else wrong. This vaguely smells like an HTML5 element issue that can be fixed with html5shiv (or Modernizr). What element are you trying to use `position: fixed` on? Just a `div`? Or a semantic HTML5 element like `nav` or `header`?

Post a link to your code so we can see what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late, but I hope it helps. Upon searching other sites/answers about all the issues with position:fixed, I've found that changing the doctype and using a metatag for X-UA-Compatable do not work for every issue. However, positioning the  for the overlay on the HTML page does make a difference. If your overlay is being obscured by other elements, put the  for the overlay after the elements that are obscuring it. It doesn't matter where this div is in the HTML DOM, right?--because it's fixed position anyway.

Comment: Heh, yeah it's a bit too late. I don't even remember where is that used. But maybe someone will find it useful. Thanks